# Set a focus point in the UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePicker control and I want to programtically select a focus point on the screen.

Is it possible through some method or property to set the focus point as a CGPoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not method for settings the focus vor [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) in the documentation.

If guess you will have to write your own camera view with [`AVCaptureSession`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you hooked up al the parts, you can use the [`focusPointOfInterest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4) property of [`AVCaptureDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to set the focus. But you should make sure that the `AVCaptureDevice` supports focus.